# Using a comma between two main verbs?

Tags: verbs, commas

(sorry if I get some of the terminology wrong, English is not my native language)

In Dutch we have the convention to place a comma between two verbs if they are not part of the same verb phrase. I was wondering if the same convention is used in English. 
Here is an example:

> How well the species adapted, remained unknown

This rule is not specifically mentioned on the websites that I checked, but I am also unsure if in Dutch this is the actual rule, or just some sort of mnemonic aid.

Comment: When speaking your example sentence, I find that I am emphasising the first verb, then pausing slightly between verbs; therefore I would put a comma in when writing it.

Comment: I've seen arguments for the inclusion of a comma between the subject and the main verb when the subject is very weighty (that is not the case here). Prescriptivists say it's always an error. But see the counter-argument given in 'The New Oxford Guide to Writing' (Thomas S. Kane) at the duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*How well the species adapted* is the subject of the verb *remained*, thus there should be no comma.

In German or Dutch, there is a comma in a similarly constructed sentence because the subject is a dependent clause.